# Poor performance when scrolling horizontally in a WPF4 DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have an application that needs to display a grid of data consisting mostly of boolean values, and checkbox columns fit the bill. There will be about 40-60 checkbox columns with around 200 rows. I thought it would be trivial to do something like that in WPF.

I am unable to even get near a decent horizontal scrolling experience with WPF. To see what I'm talking about, create a `Window` and place a `DataGrid` on it, and set `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`, then add the following in the constructor after `InitializeComponent();`:

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = Create(200, i => new { b1 = true, b2 = false, b3 = true, b4 = false, b5 = true, b6 = false, b7 = true, b8 = false, b9 = true,
                                               b10 = false, b11 = true, b12 = false, b13 = true, b14 = false, b15 = true, b16 = false, b17 = true, b18 = false, b19 = true, b20 = false, b21 = true,
                                               b22 = false, b23 = true, b24 = false, b25 = true, b26 = false, b27 = true, b28 = false, b29 = true, b30 = false, b31 = true, b32 = false });
```

It requires this method, add it too:

```
ObservableCollection<T> Create<T>(int count, Func<int, T> creator)
{
    return new ObservableCollection<T>(Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(creator));
}
```

Run the application, and attempt to scroll horizontally. Horrible, isn't it? Vertical scrolling isn't too hot either.

I did the same with a WinForms application and scrolling was butter smooth in all directions, and looked as good as WPF after forcing the `DataGridView`'s `DoubleBuffered` property to `true`. To compare, create a new `Form`, plop a `DataGridView` and add the following to the constructor after `InitializeComponent();`:

```
typeof(DataGridView).GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(dataGridView1, true, null);
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn {HeaderText = "C" + i, Width = 30});
for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
```

This has twice the number of columns, twice the number of rows, and it scrolls as smooth as a newborn's bottom, both horizontally and vertically.

But unfortunately I can't do what I need with WinForms. I need templated columns. I need composability.

To solve the scrolling issue in WPF, I tried all combinations of the following:

- EnableColumnVirtualization (true/false)
- EnableRowVirtualization (true/false)
- ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll (true/false) - `false` improves vertical scrolling only
- Fixed-sized columns
- Fixed-sized data grid
- VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode (Recycling/Standard) - <sub>`Recycling` has a bug where it will recycle a `CheckBox` control that is checked and place it in a new row where it should be unchecked, causing a fading out animation. This makes checkboxes appear to have a "ghosting" effect.</sub>
- ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled - I'm sorry but I can't accept downgrading to Windows 3.1-style scrolling for something so trivial.

I'm willing to accept subpar performance. I don't expect anything like the smoothness of WinForms (WPF is after all giving me so much more, although this should have been offset by WPF's GPU acceleration). I just want something usable, even just barely usable.

Comment: You flop between Forms and WPF and DataGrid and DataGridView.  What is the question?

Comment: @Blam: The question is how can I get WinForms-like performance in WPF when displaying a grid of data? Or even half of WinForms' performance.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem in WPF 4.5. A datagrid with 3000 rows, 6 text columns, and items are grouped. Vertical scrolling is fine, but horizontal scrolling and column resizing are horribly slow, almost unacceptably slow.  I think it should handle 3000+ row, because it is common in real-world situations, but alas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment I am not sure of the question.  If you are looking for performance of a grid in WPF then go ListView / GridView.  Unless there are some feature of DataGrid you have to have.  It is more code but worth it.   I have a GridView with 40 columns and 1000 rows and good performance (and DataGrid performance was bad).

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion. I'll try it.

Comment: I finally got around to running my test with the `ListView` using the `GridView` view. When first running it, horizontal scrolling was smooth but vertical scrolling was not. When I applied `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="false"` to the `ListView`, it incurred a startup delay (as expected) but scrolling in all direction was smooth, even with 12,800 checkboxes in the `ListView`. Resizing was also pretty quick. Only when maximizing the window, which at that size has around 2800 checkboxes in view, does the scrolling FPS slow down considerably, but remains consistent thus usable. Thanks!

Comment: Well it seems I now have a different problem. Resizing columns with a `ListView` that has even 10 columns is slow. When using more columns (say 30), you sometimes have to wait 5 to 10 seconds just for the UI to stop hanging. Have you even encountered that?

Comment: Using virtualization?  Turn on deferred scrolling.  I just tested a GridView with 24 columns and re-sizing is instantaneous.

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned in the question I cannot use deferred scrolling. And let's take scrolling out of the equation by having all rows fit on one screen (i.e. 20 rows). I just can't believe that a `ListView` with 10 columns and 20 rows leads to such poor column resizing performance. I am totally disheartened by WPF at this point. How the heck does Windows Media Center get a steady 60 FPS?

Answer (score 1):

It's mainly because CheckBox visual tree is quite complicated. You can get a lot better performance, if you restyle the visual tree.

While having only single element in ControlTemplate(single border), there was no lag or delay.
You can get specific style from here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

There will be some time spent in databinding for sure. See this:
[Databinding optimization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546.aspx), it explains that binding to usual property takes longer. Usually because it involves reflection. When using dependency properties, there is no reflection involved. As far I know.

Your class is definitely not big, but you sure can test out. Will it perform better if everything is dependency property?

Let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: I tried changing all the properties of the anonymous type to `string` (`true` -> `"true"`), and so the generated columns were simple `TextBox`es (or maybe `TextBlock`s when not in edit mode?). The performance was even worse. Do these have a complex visual tree as well?

Comment: I'll try using dependency properties to make binding faster. And I think I'll have to make my own `CheckBox` control that has simple images instead of a complex visual tree with animations that would be a plus to get rid of. I'm guessing these two things would improve further performance together with Blam's `ListView` suggestion. Thanks for these useful suggestions!

Comment: DataGrid is slow yes. You can never make something like Excel, and that's WPF's greatest weakness. TextBlock will take more time than your custom CheckBox, that's for sure. 

But the flexibility DataGrid gives you, it's amazing :).